# Festo CPX-E Codesys - Can't set any persistent variables

Tags: memory, persistent, codesys

I've been programming on our CPX-E-CEC-C1-PN but every time I just try to set one persistent variable it already says "out of memory".

Anyone ideas what setting/information I'm missing?

Comment: Not sure about the CPX-E-CEC-C1-PN, but having worked on Schneider Electric Modicon controllers, I pretty certain that Persistent variables have their own memory area, that is chosen by the PLC manufacturer and is not configurable. At lease that is true on Modicon controllers. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/0Y5CWBz.png) is the memory map of the TM241 controller (Code + Data = 10MB, Persistent Data = 32 KB). I'd recommend contacting the manufacturer support, or better yet, check their documentation to make sure that it even has ANY persistent memory

Comment: I send it back to Festo. Need to wait now for the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the available/used memory of your device to be sure that the limit is already reached.
I already used Festo Codesys and I remember that the interface is pretty similar to the Codesys interface itself. So probably you will find the memory usage in the **View -> View Memory Usage**.

[View Memory Usage image from Codesys 3.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehpvS.png)

If the persistent memory is already reached the maximum of the controller, you will need to:

- Change you approach to store the variables, changing the types in order to use less memory or, at least, use it in a mote intelligent way;
- Change the controller model to another with more memory for the persistent variables;

Answer (score 0):

Old question but i will reply for future visitors. You need to perform a clean all. this will redefine the memory and allow you to add more persistent variables.